# How to compile netcat-openbsd on Solaris 10 (Sparc Sun4v)

Tags: gcc, makefile, solaris

Do you know how to compile netcat-openbsd on Solaris 10 (Sparc Sun4v).

I downloaded netcat-openbsd_1.187.orig.tar.gz from following URL.
https://ftp.vcu.edu/pub/gnu_linux/ubuntu/pool/main/n/netcat-openbsd/netcat-openbsd_1.187.orig.tar.gz

```
$ gmake
Makefile:8: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Just for the record, here is the content of the "Makefile" file.

```
#       $OpenBSD: Makefile,v 1.7 2015/09/11 21:07:01 beck Exp $

PROG=   nc
SRCS=   netcat.c atomicio.c socks.c
LDADD+= -ltls -lssl -lcrypto
DPADD+=  ${LIBTLS} ${LIBSSL} ${LIBCRYPTO}

.include <bsd.prog.mk>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am the one who actually ported OpenBSD Netcat to Solaris back in 2007 to be available in official Solaris packages [1]; it is available to this day in Solaris 11 as `network/netcat` IPS package and it is maintained. That was still in the OpenSolaris days and I believe the work still lives on as open source in the Illumos repository.

Anyway, in order to compile the specific Netcat source code referenced in the question, you have to port it first.

You have already noticed that the Makefile supplied with the source code does not work with GNU make. In fact, it does not even work with with the make implementation supplied with Solaris. This is because the BSD make specific directive on the last line of the Makefile.

Assuming you have the latest greatest patch level of Solaris (something like CPU 2021-04 - CPU stands for Critical Patch Update), there will be quite a few changes necessary to the source code. When I ported the OpenBSD Netcat, it was fairly minimal w.r.t. features. It has since added bunch of stuff, including TLS support etc. These can be noticed in the Makefile already where you can see it wants to link the program with OpenSSL libraries. On Solaris 10, this is a bit complicated since it delivers two versions of OpenSSL. These are the parts you will likely want to disable (by modifying both the source code and the Makefile) in order to get minimal functionality.

Then once you have a working program, you can work on enabling the so far disabled features, at least those you care about.

Easier way would be to get the older version of OpenBSD Netcat or perhaps grab the Netcat source code from Illumos (assuming you do not care about licensing etc.).

As for compiler choice, either GNU CC or Oracle Developer Studio will do.

[1] you can read about it in my now salvaged blog entry here: https://github.com/vladak/blogs-oracle/blob/master/netcat-in-solaris.html